# Iterate a SQL Query through multiple parameters one at a time and union the results

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012

I have a query I have written for SQL Server 2012 to take a dynamic list of personnel and determine how long they spend each day in certain areas. When I run the query a person at a time, I get good results. However, if I pass all the parameters within an IN clause then I not only get less results, but some of the values are different and just plain wrong.

This will eventually be run within a report in SSRS, but even running the data straight in SSMS it is showing the same behavior.

The `@People` is a separate query that gathers a list of the people which were actually in the area that day. `@Yesterday` and `@Today` are just variables for dates.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         AdmitType,
         Time,
         Person,
         Door,
         Direction,
         CASE 
            WHEN Direction LIKE 'In' AND LEAD(Direction, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Time ASC) LIKE 'Out'
               THEN DATEDIFF (second, Time, LEAD(Time, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Time ASC))
               ELSE NULL
         END AS 'Duration'
     FROM 
         ActivityLog
     WHERE 
         Door IN ('Room1', 'Room2', 'Room3')
         AND Time BETWEEN @Yesterday AND @Today
         AND Person IN @People) s1
ORDER BY 
    Person, Door, Time ASC
```

If I run the above query and pass the `@People` parameter with a value of `('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry')` then I will get something like this back for Tom's entries (eliminating some columns and multiple people and doors for clarity):

```
Time    Direction    Duration  
-----------------------------
7:12:04 IN           922  
7:27:26 OUT          NULL  
8:40:37 IN           NULL  
9:07:04 OUT          NULL
```

But If I run the query with just Tom listed in the IN clause, I get the following which is correct:

```
Time    Direction    Duration  
-----------------------------
7:12:04 IN           922  
7:27:26 OUT          NULL  
8:40:37 IN           1587  
9:07:04 OUT          NULL
```

How can I either fix my query so that it returns the correct information with everyone selected (approximately 25 people usually) or take the parameter and run each person one at a time and union the results?

I have seen a query which passes a list one at a time and unions all the results, but I do not know how to write that in such a way as to accept the parameter input that would be passed from SSRS.

Additional Data Added from Alan Schofield suggestion:
When I added the PARTITION BY Clause I am now getting data for those previous NULLs, but it is not correct data.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         AdmitType,
         Time,
         Person,
         Door,
         Direction,
         CASE 
            WHEN Direction LIKE 'In' AND LEAD(Direction, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Person, Door ORDER BY Time ASC) LIKE 'Out'
               THEN DATEDIFF (second, Time, LEAD(Time, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Time ASC))
               ELSE NULL
         END AS 'Duration'
     FROM 
         ActivityLog
     WHERE 
         Door IN ('Room1', 'Room2', 'Room3')
         AND Time BETWEEN @Yesterday AND @Today
         AND Person IN @People) s1
ORDER BY 
    Person, Door, Time ASC
```

HERE is a larger example data set with the new PARTITION BY clause results:

```
Time      Person     Door    Direction    Duration  
18:07:22  John       Room1   IN           1308  (Correct)
18:29:10  John       Room1   Out          NULL  
17:42:18  John       Room3   IN           1406  (Correct)
18:05:44  John       Room3   Out          NULL
7:12:04   Tom        Room1   IN           922   (Correct)
7:27:26   Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
8:40:37   Tom        Room1   IN           2    (Previously NULL, Now 2, should be 1587 and is when queried alone)
9:07:04   Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
9:09:07   Tom        Room1   IN           31   (Previously NULL, Now 31, should be 1256 and is when queried alone)
9:30:03   Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
9:38:48   Tom        Room1   IN           48   (Correct)
9:39:36   Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
9:39:45   Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
9:40:36   Tom        Room1   IN           90   (Correct)
9:42:06   Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
10:25:0   Tom        Room1   IN           47   (Previously 47, Now 47, Should be 8939 and is when queried alone)
12:54:08  Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
14:09:42  Tom        Room1   IN           39   (Correct)
14:10:21  Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
14:39:03  Tom        Room1   IN           1316 (Previously NULL, Now 1316, should be 4178 and is when queried alone)
15:48:41  Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
15:49:20  Tom        Room1   IN           52   (Previously NULL, Now 52, should be 1542 and is when queried alone)
16:15:02  Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
16:22:26  Tom        Room1   IN           292  (Previously 292, Now 292, should be 1504 and is when queried alone)
16:47:30  Tom        Room1   Out          NULL
```

The data continues a lot more but hopefully this gives a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause is incorrect in the sense that it's not going to return the results you think.

> If I run the above query and pass the @People parameter with a value
>   of ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry')

This is incorrect. `@People` does not have a value of ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry'). It has a value of ('Tom, Dick, Harry').

```
WHERE 
     Door IN ('Room1', 'Room2', 'Room3')
     AND Time BETWEEN @Yesterday AND @Today
     AND Person IN @People) s1
```

Field `Door`'s IN clause lists three distinct values, separated by T-SQL commas, and correctly filters the query.

You need to have a table-valued function to split the `@People` parameter into a table variable, and use that for the Person IN clause. Something like this:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[SplitListToTable]
(
    @List       AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  AS NVARCHAR(8) = ','
 )
RETURNS @SplitList TABLE (ListItem [nvarchar](4000))
BEGIN

DECLARE @NextString     AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Pos            AS INT
DECLARE @NextPos        AS INT
DECLARE @DelimiterCheck AS NVARCHAR(1)

--Initialize
SET @NextString = ''
SET @DelimiterCheck = RIGHT(@List, 1) 

IF (@DelimiterCheck <> @Delimiter )
    SET @List = @List + @Delimiter

--Get position of first Comma
SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List)
SET @NextPos = 1

--Loop while there is still a comma in the String of levels
WHILE (@pos <>  0)  
    BEGIN
    SET @NextString = SUBSTRING(@List, 1, @Pos - 1)

    INSERT INTO @SplitList(ListItem) Values(@NextString)

    SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, @Pos +1, LEN(@List))
    SET @NextPos = @Pos
    SET @Pos  = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List)
    END

RETURN

END
GO
```

Now, update your WHERE clause as such:

```
AND Person IN dbo.SplitListToTable(@People, ',')
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, I removed my parameter entirely and hard coded in the values in so it reads AND Person IN ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry') and I get the same incorrect results.  I went ahead and tried your suggestion, because I have seen SQL do some things I can't explain and got the same results.  I've also tried hard coding in values for all the parameters just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a PARTITION BY to you Windowed functions. At the moment

```
LEAD(Direction, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Time ASC)
```

Is looking for the next record, regardless of which person is referenced in the record. Try adding the PARTITION BY clause to the relevant windowed functons.

```
LEAD(Direction, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Time ASC)
```

I'm not sure if you need to include Door in windowed functions too, hard to know without seeing the data.
If this does not help, please edit your question to show some sample data and expected results based on the sample data.

Comment: I had originally included a statement to look by person and obviously I had something wrong in that query because it was not changing anything.  Adding this PARTITION BY I am now getting data for those fields that were previously NULL but not the correct Data.  I also tried adding the door into the PARTITION BY clause.  I will update my question.

Comment: OK, just give some sample data and expected output and I'm sure you'll get an answer

Comment: Added, If a larger sample size is needed, let me know and I will get more data sanitized.